# How can Navigate to the chosen region 5 times (1 fresh, 4 cached) in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario that should Navigate to the chosen region 5 times (1 fresh, 4 cached) in jmeter. how can I perform this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a unique string to your URL, so that it bypasses the cache first time, and use the same URL 4 more times, so that it hits cache.

Ex: http://somedomain/somepath?random=time stamp+some random number

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) to your test plan and set "Loop Count" to 5
2. Make your HTTP Request sampler which hits your URL a child of the Loop Controller. Make sure that "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" and "Use Concurrent Pool" boxes are checked.
3. Add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager) to your Test Plan - it'll handle browser's cache simulation automatically